# Rails: AJAX Controller JS not firing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having an issue with one of my controller's AJAX functionality.  Here's what I have:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.image_content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(@photo.image_file_name).to_s
    @photo.image_width = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(params[:photo][:image]).width.to_i
    @photo.image_height = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(params[:photo][:image]).height.to_i
    @photo.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

This is called through a `POST` request sent by this code:

```
$(function() {
  // add photos link
  $('a.add-photos-link').colorbox({
    overlayClose: false,
    onComplete: function() { wire_add_photo_modal(); }
  });

  function wire_add_photo_modal() {
    <% session_key = ActionController::Base.session_options[:key] %>
    $('#upload_photo').uploadify({
      uploader: '/swf/uploadify.swf',
      script: '/photos',
      cancelImg: '/images/buttons/cancel.png',
      buttonText: 'Upload Photo(s)',
      auto: true,
      queueID: 'queue',
      fileDataName: 'photo[image]',
      scriptData: {
        '<%= session_key %>': '<%= u cookies[session_key] %>',
        commit: 'Adding Photo',
        controller: 'photos',
        action: 'create',
        '_method': 'post',
        'photo[gallery_id]': $('#gallery_id').val(),
        'photo[user_id]': $('#user_id').val(),
        authenticity_token: encodeURIComponent('<%= u form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery? %>')
      },
      multi: true
    });
  }
});
```

Finally, I have my response code in `app/views/photos/create.js.erb`:

```
alert('photo added!');
```

My log file shows that the request was successful (the photo was successfully uploaded), and it even says that it rendered the `create` action, yet I never get the alert.  My browser shows NO javascript errors.

Here's the log AFTER a request from the above `POST` request is submitted:

```
Processing PhotosController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-03-16 14:35:33) [POST]
Parameters: {"Filename"=>"tumblr_kx74k06IuI1qzt6cxo1_400.jpg", "photo"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "image"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20100316-54303-7r2npu-0>}, "commit"=>"Adding Photo", "_edited_session"=>"edited", "folder"=>"/kakagiloon/", "authenticity_token"=>"edited", "action"=>"create", "_method"=>"post", "Upload"=>"Submit Query", "controller"=>"photos"}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving /public/images/assets/kakagiloon/thumbnail/tumblr_kx74k06IuI1qzt6cxo1_400.jpg
[paperclip] saving /public/images/assets/kakagiloon/profile/tumblr_kx74k06IuI1qzt6cxo1_400.jpg
[paperclip] saving /public/images/assets/kakagiloon/original/tumblr_kx74k06IuI1qzt6cxo1_400.jpg
Rendering photos/create
Completed in 248ms (View: 1, DB: 6) | 200 OK [http://edited.local/photos]
```

NOTE: I edited out all the SQL statements and I put "edited" in place of sensitive info.

What gives? Why aren't I getting my `alert();`?

Please let me know if you need anymore info to help me solve this issue! Thanks.

---

SOLUTION:  Thanks to jitter for setting me straight about Uploadify's callbacks.

Controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.image_content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(@photo.image_file_name).to_s
    @photo.image_width = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(params[:photo][:image]).width.to_i
    @photo.image_height = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(params[:photo][:image]).height.to_i
    @photo.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Javascript (Uploadify) callback:

```
$(function() {
  // add photos link
  $('a.add-photos-link').colorbox({
    overlayClose: false,
    onComplete: function() { wire_add_photo_modal($(this).parent()); }
  });

  function wire_add_photo_modal($parent) {
    <% session_key = ActionController::Base.session_options[:key] %>
    $('#upload_photo').uploadify({
      uploader: '/swf/uploadify.swf',
      script: '/photos',
      cancelImg: '/images/buttons/cancel.png',
      buttonText: 'Upload Photo(s)',
      auto: true,
      queueID: 'queue',
      fileDataName: 'photo[image]',
      scriptData: {
        '<%= session_key %>': '<%= u cookies[session_key] %>',
        commit: 'Adding Photo',
        controller: 'photos',
        action: 'create',
        '_method': 'post',
        'photo[gallery_id]': $('#gallery_id').val(),
        'photo[user_id]': $('#user_id').val(),
        authenticity_token: encodeURIComponent('<%= u form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery? %>')
      },
      multi: true,
      onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) { 
        $parent.find('.gallery-photos').append(response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In `create.js.haml` (changed templating language from ERB, since I'm basically just returning HTML content):

```
- if @photo.gallery.nil?
  =render :partial => 'photos/photo', :locals => { :photo => @photo, :rel => 'unsorted' }
- else
  = render :partial => 'photos/photo', :locals => { :photo => @photo, :rel => gallery.title }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see that you use any of uploadify's callbacks. Thus I guess it just ignores whatever the server sends as response. Try wiring up the `onComplete` option with a function if you want to send a meaningful response back to your javascript

Check the [uploadify documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) for more

I imagine you could change `app/views/photos/create.js.erb` to

```
photo added!
```

and then do

```
$('#upload_photo').uploadify({
    ...
    onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
        alert("Server said: "+response+" for file "+fileObj.name);
    }
    ...
});
```

---

If you want to add the photo to the page you can just let the server return the appropriate html snippet e.g. I imagine create.js.erb to create/output something like this

```
<img src="Xxx.jpg" width="..." height="..." />
```

All you need to do in the callback is

```
onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
    $("selectorforwheretheimageshouldbeinserted").append(response);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The alert was just as a demonstration; I actually want to add the photo onto the page (AJAX update). I couldn't get this to work using Uploadify's callback since it's not aware of the new `@photo` object created by Rails, whereas the `create.js.erb` is. If I make Uploadify's `OnComplete` return false, however, I lose it's nice little auto-clear of the queue behavior (what it does by default, out of the box). Any ideas for a workaround?